# Why numeric type are in form p[,s], where p=number+s?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, numeric

Why they didn't create numeric type like "integer1,integer2", why i have to calculate the sum of both sides for p (i need to subtract s from p to get actual amount)?

Comment: Please give a specific example demonstrating what problem you are having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The SQL standard is designed for a specific purpose: to query data
>   contained in a relational database.

Here are some of the implementations of this standard:

[image]

So, basically, a long time ago, the people who were working over the standard have decided [that](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt), for `6.1  <data type>` of the `numeric` we have:

[image]

and

[image]

However, extensions to Standard SQL exists but each implementation try to follow it.